# Passing numeration in while loop to inner function which was passed as a outer function variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I am trying to run a function as a variable in another function, however the first function has a variable that is only being specified in the second function. I do not think it is good practice, but I guess I programmed myself in a corner.

```
def in_func(n, p):
    print(p)
    print(f'Num {n}')

def out_func(func):
    n = 0
    while n < 10:
        func(n)
        n += 1
p = 8
out_func(in_func(n, p))
```

What is the best practice or solution to a problem such as this?

Comment: You want `out_func(in_func)`

Comment: This maybe a case for decorators, but it is not completely clear what you are ultimately trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *calling* `in_func` and passing the result to `out_func`. Instead, you can e.g. define a `lambda` function that accepts only the `n` parameter while using `p` from the current scope...

```
p = 8
out_func(lambda n: in_func(n, p))
```

... or use `functools.partial` to the same effect:

```
from functools import partial
p = 8
out_func(partial(in_func, p=p))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `n` when passing the `in_func` as an argument:

```
def in_func(n):
    print(f'Num {n}')


def out_func(func):
    n = 0
    while n < 10:
        func(n)
        n += 1


out_func(in_func)
```

**Edit**

Pretending the updated syntax works and does something meaningful (had to adjust to even run it), I guess your only option would be to declare the `n` variable globally. Then returning `in_func` from itself to be called by `out_func`:

```
def in_func(n, p):
    print(p)
    print(f'Num {n}')
    return in_func


def out_func(func):
    global n
    n = 0
    while n < 10:
        func(n, p)
        n += 1


n = 10
p = 8
out_func(in_func(n, p))
```

In the end, maybe they don't need to be the same variable?

```
def in_func(n, p):
    print(p)
    print(f'Num {n}')
    return in_func


def out_func(func):
    n_b = 0
    while n_b < 10:
        func(n_b, p)
        n_b += 1


n_a = 10
p = 8
out_func(in_func(n_a, p))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But please see my updated question where I need a variable assigned outside the out_func as well and passed to the in_func. The in_func functions and their parameters will keep changing but all need the n variable passed inside the out_func.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect on the matter

Comment: `return in_func` creates a closure, which IMHO makes only sense with nested functions. You are then passing this closure as parameter to `out_func`, but don't use any feature of closures. So, you may as well call `out_func(in_func)`as already proposed by @Matthias as comment to the question.

Comment: That was my initial answer as well. I was just throwing ideas on screen as they say, but seem to be running in circles here. Maybe I just didn't quite catch the intention. Maybe the `lambda` approach is something that you're looking for?

Comment: @LTJ I just mean that letting `in_func` returning itself as return value is not really useful. If only allows you to call `out_func(inc_func(some,params))` which causes an additional call to `in_func` which is completely useless.